# Xcode 11 Upgrade | Could not find iPhone X simulator | XRPackageModel 9.0.omo

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode11

Anyone else getting this since upgrading from [Xcode 10.3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_3_release_notes) to [Xcode 11](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes) when running `react-native run-ios` and any idea to get back up and running?

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'
error Could not find iPhone X simulator
```

Comment: Sorry, reopened. I misinterpreted a duplicate answer posting, confusing two authors.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: We've had to downgrade back to Xcode 10.3 in the end based on the complexity of our dependencies, so back to running iPhone X simulator on all versions of iOS as normal. Back to playing the waiting game with a beady eye.

Comment: I get this error using `instruments -s devices`. Does any one have the same problem?

Comment: @PedroSilva This would make sense and is expected when it comes to reaching listing your `iPhone X` devices the same way `react-native run-ios` looks for the `iPhone X` by default. So in theory the temporary fix should solve.

Comment: @JuanguiJordán Just to clarify, this question was asked earlier _Sept 23_; the question you have linked was asked later _Oct 2_. The appropriate etiquette is to flag the the latter as a duplicate and vote to close it, not the original.

Comment: Ok, @Leo, I will try, but one of the admins removed my answer here, I don't know if I will be able to handle all the changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, it won't let me post my answer here again, then flag the other one as duplicate of this one

Comment: @JuanguiJordán Hmm I wonder why it was removed. I'd remove your previous comment to prevent further confusion, then write a new comment here something like: _Possible answer: <share-link>_

Comment: Possible answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207838/react-native-run-ios-could-not-find-iphone-x-simulator-xrpackagemodel-9-0-omo/58266877#58266877

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I remember this happening before and amending:

`node_modules⁩ ▸ ⁨@react-native-community⁩ ▸ ⁨cli⁩ ▸ ⁨build⁩ ▸ ⁨commands⁩ ▸ ⁨runIOS⁩ ▸ findMatchingSimulator.js`

As a current workaround, updating:

```
if (simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES') {
  continue;
}
```

To:

```
if (simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== true) {
  continue;
}
```

Seems to get me back up and running.

Hopefully this gets updated pronto.

---

`"react-native": "^0.59.3"`

Comment: what version of react-native?

Comment: `^0.59.3`, mid-upgrading to `^0.60.5`

Comment: @Ilario Oops yes very important detail - added

Answer (score 10):

Xcode 11 can't see iPhoneX or Other Simulator 
- First need to add new Simulator
- Then click on the bottom left of the Simulator then choose device you wanna add

[image: First need to add new Simulator]

[image: Then click on the bottom left of the Simulator then choose device you wanna add]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but this has already been covered, scroll down: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060484/xcode-11-upgrade-could-not-find-iphone-x-simulator-xrpackagemodel-9-0-omo/58539400#comment102523781_58063709. I.e. This does _not_ work.

Answer (score 4):

Open xcode and go to window > Device and Simulators... go to the Simulators tab and click the + in the bottom left, here you can add iphone X.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but the iPhone X and subsequently other simulators are already added. Removing then re-adding them has no effect.

Comment: The iPhone X simulator wasn't already added in my specific use case, so this and the answer above were the solutions for me

Comment: This answer still works in 2021 January for Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default simulator to use.

`react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro Max"`

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, yes this command runs a specified simulator, but this does not run the `iPhone X simulator`. In this context, `X` stands for `10`, not any generic version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a `@react-native/cli` version that doesn't detect XCode 11 simulators. You can either downgrade your XCode or install a `@react-native/cli` that supports [it](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/releases/tag/v1.9.8).

If you are not managing the version of `@react-native/cli` directly in your `package.json` you can simply remove your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` file and install it again:

```
rm yarn.lock 
yarn install
```

or

```
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```